# In requests-python, when is connection released when using req_json = req.json()?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I read the following on python-requests website:

> Note that connections are only released back to the pool for reuse once all body data has been read; be sure to either set stream to False or read the content property of the Response object.

But as I use the object returned by req.json() and doesn't use req thereafter. I wonder when is the connection released? I don't really know how to check that for sure too.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could answer your question quite simpply by reading the source code. But anyway: `response.json()` does read the `response`'s content, obviously - it's just a convenient shortcut for `json.loads(response.content)`.